# Galaxy Note 2 N7100 does not turn on, only shows battery "loading" icon

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I bought a GN2 three days ago, it worked fine until today, when I did a reboot and it didn't come back. The blue LED turned off with the device, and instead of rebooting, the battery "loading" (empty battery with a loading icon) screen appeared. This screen flashes up every 15 seconds or so.

If I plug in the phone to the charger, the battery loading screen stops appearing and the red charging LED appears. However, if I hold the power button to turn the device on, the battery "loading" icon reappears and after a few seconds, it goes back to the red charging LED and charging screen.

The battery has 60% charge, so it is not dead.

I can boot into system recovery by pressing volume up + home + power every single time. Selecting "reboot device now" from the recovery sometimes boots the device, and sometimes does not.

Occasionally I can get it to boot in the normal manner (by holding the power button), but there seems to be no pattern between when I can boot it by pressing the power button and when I can't.

Just before this battery loading screen appears, there is a very brief flash of red from the LED.

I am not aware of doing anything that should mess with the bootloader or ROM. The device is running the stock ROM and the bootloader is locked.

I have tried removing the battery for a few minutes, which did not resolve the issue (it turns on after the battery is inserted, but afterwards this issue reoccurs).

Comment: Try this: http://droidtricks.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-boot-samsung-galaxy-note-into.html It worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: I replaced the phone a few days after I made this post. I haven't had the issue with the new phone. Sorry for not being able to provide a good answer!